# Understanding Get With Auth

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get, http-get

In fiddler I have the following header:

```
GET http://localhost:49676/api/values HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: Bearer xCatZFPvw8LjQPGrWvQyvITVewWmuUHk...
Host: localhost:49676
```

How do I run something like this in an address url bar on the browser?  Or can't I?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that approach using Postman. I'm afraid you won't be able to set the HTTP headers in the browser URL.